# why Number.parseInt and global's parseInt are differents?

Tags: javascript, firefox, ecmascript-6

In MDN's [Number.parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt) section, it says that:

> The Number.parseInt() method parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix or base. ***This method behaves identically to the global function parseInt()*** and is part of ECMAScript 6 (its purpose is modularization of globals).

.. but the following code yields `false` on latest firefox

```
console.log(Number.parseInt == parseInt)
```

So are they just the *same*?

Comment: I have not tested on latest firefox, but on Chrome its just the same console.log(parseInt == Number.parseInt); ==> true

Comment: *behaves identically* doesn't imply that they're the same function references.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK your comparison (when applied to Functions) tests whether it's the exact same instance of Function, which is not - they just happen to have similar **content** (code) inside. You can easily test it by defining your own 2 functions that just happen to contain similar code, e.g. "{alert('hi')}" in both. You'll see they are not "=="

Comment: so are you saying that they both have different implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I tried looking into the C/C++ code of webkit, but I'm not familiar with the low-level commands used there. It could well be two javascript "Function" instances that point to the same native code, but I'm really not sure - sorry.